# Subfolders are tracked as direct traffic with Google Analytics: force to treat it as referrals

Tags: google-analytics

I have different websites in the same domain:

```
chelder.mepage.us --> GetSimple CMS
chelder.mepage.us/blogchina --> WordPress CMS
chelder.mepage.us/armenia --> Question2Answer CMS
...
```

I want to track `chelder.mepage.us` only. I have added the Google Analytics script. It is working propertly. I have added **links from the other subdirectories to `chelder.mepage.us`**. The issue is that it is **detected as direct (and not set) traffic**. How could I change this behavior to see who enter in `chelder.mepage.us` from those subdirectories?

Comment: Untested (hence a comment rather than an answer), but you could try  to set up an advanced filter on your view that captures the value from  the request uri (for top-domain visits) and pushes it to the "referral" field (or maybe campaign referal path ? You might have to experiment a little).

Comment: Okay, a short test later that seems to work (in the real time view at least), but you have to set both campaign medium and campaign source (i.e. use two filters). I'm not yet sure if this will be properly aggregated in the reports with "real" referrers, but at first look this seems  promising.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, so I go to Admin - Filters (at the VIEW column) - New filter. Then? Include only traffic to the subdirectories that end with blogchina? I don't think so... The user interface of Google Analytics is very confusing for me :(

Comment: I will test if this actually works as we hope - if it does  I'll post a guide (but that will take until tomorrow).

Comment: Take your time @EikePierstorff! Thank you! :)

Comment: Btw. the answer might be a lot easier - if you set up a new account with Universal Analytics your domain will be automatically added to the referral exclusion list (in admin->property settings->trackong code). If you remove that traffic between domains and subdomains will automatically show up as referrals.

Comment: @EikePierstorff, I guess Universal Analytics is activated by default now because I have not found the _Universal Analytics Upgrade_ option at the _PROPERTY_ column. Do you mean clicking on _Use enhanced link attribution_ in _Property Settings_? :/